# What are the best practices for converting existing iPhone navigation systems into a Split View navigation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I am trying to figure out how to best convert many of may apps to Split View apps for the new iPad.  What are some of the best ways to go about this, minimizing the amount of transition code needed?

Remember, the code is under NDA, but discussing generalities on the design architecture is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I have done is making screenshots of the Keynote and that Ive movie. They show a lot of application in them and for now those are the best hints on how to do good UI design for the iPad I'm afraid. The mail app is a really nice example of the split view I think.